# Why am I getting "NotFound" reponse when attempting to get a list of repositories with the GitHub API?

Tags: curl, github-api

I am trying to get the list of repositories for an authenticated user with the following curl command as per the [GitHub documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user)

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token <token>" https://api.github.com/nrkirby/repos
```

and always receive a `NotFound` response.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I've generated a token with *all* permissions to rule out an issue with the token

Answer (score 1):

You should use just `/user/repos`

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
 -H "Authorization: token <token>" \
 https://api.github.com/user/repos
```